# Unable to add string at the end using STUFF

Tags: sql-server

I tried to Insert a string within another string using `STUFF`.

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(100) = '12345'

SELECT  STUFF(@Number, 3, 0, '6') -- Add value in 3rd Position, Returns '126345'
```

I tried to append the value at the end

```
SELECT  STUFF(@Number, 6, 0, '6') -- Add value in 6th Position
-- Actual length is 5, So it Returns 'NULL'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
123456
```

I tried using `STUFF` for simple statement. But **not able to append string at the end**. Can anyone help me to do in any other simple way?

Comment: What output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` to append strings one after the other. They will be appended in the order in which they are passed to the function:

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(100) = '12345'
select concat(@Number,'6')
```

You can also use the '+' operator for this purpose. However, if one the strings being appended is NULL, the result will also be NULL using '+', whereas the NULL string is treated as a blank string by `CONCAT`.

```
select concat(@Number,null,6) -- = '123456'
select @Number + null + 6 -- == null
```

If the position to insert is not fixed, you can use a `CASE` statement along with `STUFF` and `CONCAT` to either insert into or append in a single statement, like so:

```
declare @number varchar(100) = '12345'
declare @pos int = 6
declare @append varchar(100) = '6'

select 
case 
     when @pos < len(@number) then stuff(@number,@pos,0,@append) 
     else concat(@number,@append) 
end result
```

Comment: How to insert string in the middle?

Comment: `STUFF` would be suitable for that. In general, I would use `STUFF` to insert into a string, and `CONCAT` to join several strings one after other.

Comment: So based on condition I need to do... Is it possible in single statement?

Comment: @Jesuraja See my updated code. I believe that would be acceptable as one statement?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

> The second paramter is an integer value that specifies the location to
>   start deletion and insertion. If start or length is negative, a null
>   string is returned. **If start is longer than the first
>   character_expression, a null string is returned.** start can be of type
>   bigint.

This query :

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(100) = '12345'
SELECT  STUFF(@Number, 6, 0, '6')
```

return NULL because there is only 5 characters.

If you want append string at the end just concat that string using `+` operator.

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(100) = '12345'
SELECT @Number + '6'
```

Comment: How to insert string in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

As a hack you can do this,

```
SELECT  STUFF(@Number, 5, 1, '56')
```

Comment: Your idea is good... Replace last char with last char + new value... So we need to change the 3rd parameter based on condition... right?

Comment: Yes, but it depends where you want to use it, it will require a bit manual work. Please see to other ans also, they have given very good explanation.